# Shibboleth setup - reverse proxy wtih Nginx to Jetty 9.4.9

Tags: shibboleth, jetty-9, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm setting up Shibboleth to use SAML 2.0. This setup contains reverse proxy using Nginx to Jetty 9.49 which points to shibboleth idp.war file.
For testing, I'm using the django Service provider from this example [here](http://codeinpython.blogspot.sg/2015/11/how-to-setup-shibboleth-identity.html).

I'm using self-sign certificates.

I can access both https://idp.localhost/idp/shibboleth and https://idp.localhost/idp/status, but not https://idp.localhost/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO. From shibboleth log file, I'm getting this error each time I browse https://idp.localhost/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO:

> 2018-04-25 18:20:47,746 - ERROR
>   [org.opensaml.saml.common.binding.security.impl.ReceivedEndpointSecurityHandler:200]
>   - Message Handler:  SAML message intended destination endpoint 'https://idp.localhost/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO' did not match the
>   recipient endpoint 'http://idp.localhost/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO'
>
> ==> idp-warn.log <== 2018-04-25 18:20:47,746 - ERROR [org.opensaml.saml.common.binding.security.impl.ReceivedEndpointSecurityHandler:200]
>   - Message Handler:  SAML message intended destination endpoint 'https://idp.localhost/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO' did not match the
>   recipient endpoint 'http://idp.localhost/idp/profile/SAML2/POST/SSO'
>
> ==> idp-process.log <== 2018-04-25 18:20:47,748 - WARN [net.shibboleth.idp.profile.impl.WebFlowMessageHandlerAdaptor:202] -
>   Profile Action WebFlowMessageHandlerAdaptor: Exception handling
>   message org.opensaml.messaging.handler.MessageHandlerException: SAML
>   message failed received endpoint check    at
>   org.opensaml.saml.common.binding.security.impl.ReceivedEndpointSecurityHandler.checkEndpointURI(ReceivedEndpointSecurityHandler.java:202)
>
> ==> idp-warn.log <== 2018-04-25 18:20:47,748 - WARN [net.shibboleth.idp.profile.impl.WebFlowMessageHandlerAdaptor:202] -
>   Profile Action WebFlowMessageHandlerAdaptor: Exception handling
>   message org.opensaml.messaging.handler.MessageHandlerException: SAML
>   message failed received endpoint check    at
>   org.opensaml.saml.common.binding.security.impl.ReceivedEndpointSecurityHandler.checkEndpointURI(ReceivedEndpointSecurityHandler.java:202)
>
> ==> idp-process.log <== 2018-04-25 18:20:47,749 - WARN [org.opensaml.profile.action.impl.LogEvent:105] - A non-proceed event
>   occurred while processing the request: MessageAuthenticationError
>
> ==> idp-warn.log <== 2018-04-25 18:20:47,749 - WARN [org.opensaml.profile.action.impl.LogEvent:105] - A non-proceed event
>   occurred while processing the request: MessageAuthenticationError

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think that a request was done in HTTPS and a response returned in clear HTTP. 
This kind of problem sometimes happen when jetty was non installed from source or with other corrupted packages. It's difficult to diagnose in this situation.

Try to compile jetty from source, clean first your old installation.

I've also build up a complete IDP/SP setup procedure with apache2 or nginx/ tomcat or jetty setup here, with ansible:

https://github.com/peppelinux/Ansible-Shibboleth-IDP-SP-Debian9

It takes 4 minutes to give you what you expect, It needs an existing LDAP installation.